# Calculating limit of specific sequence obtained from Fibonacci's sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

**Problem**: Let sequence $x_n$ be defined by:

$$x_0=0,$$ 
$$x_1=\tanh{c}, \text{ } c\in\mathbb{R}$$ 
$$x_{n+2}=\frac{x_{n+1}+x_n}{1+x_{n+1}x_n}, \text{ for } n\geq 0. $$

Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$.

**Solution** I should use that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$, but I don't know how to prove that fact.

Any help or hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $y_n=\tanh^{-1}x_n$.

Comment: I think you must be wrong about that limit. Use @LordSharktheUnknown's hint to get a recursive definition of $y_n$, and all will become clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clarify the implications of the suggested substitution $x_n=\tanh y_n$.

Since $y_n$ is a Fibonacci sequence, the correct statement is$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\color{limegreen}{\frac{y_n}{y_{n+1}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\color{limegreen}{\frac{\operatorname{artanh}x_n}{\operatorname{artanh}x_{n+1}}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}.$$So $$\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=\infty,\,\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$$if $c>0$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=-\infty,\,\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=-1$$if $c<0$, or$$x_n=y_n=0$$for all $n\ge0$ if $c=0$. We may write $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\operatorname{sgn}c$.

Comment: Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n=\infty$ when [Wolframalpha says] (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+tanh%5E%28-1%29%28n%29+as+n-%3Einfinity)

Comment: Also, check this answer [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462275/limit-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac12-ln-frac1x1-x-fraci-pi2]. Could you please correct your answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @alans My answer is correct. You seem to think $y_n$ behaves for large $n$ like $\operatorname{artanh}n$; it's actually $cF_n$, whereas $x_n=\tanh(cF_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The recursive formula for $x_{n + 2}$ suggests using the sum identity for the hyperbolic tangent:
$$\tanh (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\tanh \alpha + \tanh \beta}{1 + \tanh \alpha \tanh \beta} .$$

Comment: How to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

Comment: This identity suggests setting (as LordSharkTheUnknown suggested in his comment) $x_n = \tanh y_n$, when the identity gives that $y_{n + 2} = y_{n + 1} + y_n$. At this point all you need to know is that (provided $c \neq 0$, in which case $x_n = 0$)  $y_n$ is monotone and unbounded, so $y_n \to \pm \infty$ and thus $x_n = \operatorname{artanh} y_n \to \pm 1$.

Comment: You don't need it to resolve the problem, but the recursion rule we found for $y$ is the same as the one in the Fibonacci sequence, so by linearity $y_n = cF_n$, where $(F_n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence with the convention $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$. Then, it follows from Binet's formula that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{y_{n + 1}}{y_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n + 1}}{F_n} = \phi := \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt 5) .$$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html