# Limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\ln{(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}=\frac{i\pi}{2}?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

How to prove that $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\ln{(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}=\frac{i\pi}{2}?$$
I got that answer by using WolframAlpha, but I don't know how to deduce it.

Any help or hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})=\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{1/x+1}{1/x-1})$

so limit = $\frac{1}{2}ln(-1)=\frac{1}{2}ln(e^{i\pi})=\frac{i\pi}{2}$

PS: $e^{i\pi}=cos(\pi)+ i sin(\pi)=-1$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln(x)$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1+x}{1-x} = -1$, the limit is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\ln{(-1)} = \frac{\pi i}{2}$.

Two supplemental points:

- To see that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1+x}{1-x} = -1$, divide the numerator and denominator both by $x$ and compute $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1 + 1/x}{-1+1/x}$. The limit as $x \to \infty$ exists for both numerator and denominator so the limit of the fraction is $-1$.
- $\ln(-1) = \pi i$ because $e^{\pi i} = -1$.